# Remove duplicates from an array which contains array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON array like this

```
[{"Email":"someone@some.com","Name":"ACO","Groups":["MOD_SW","MOD_PI","MOD_GE"],"Id":63,"Url":"aco"},
{"Email":"someone@some.com","Name":"Agpo","Groups":["MOD_PI"],"Id":22,"Url":"agpo"},
{"Email":"someone@some.com","Name":"Akatherm","Groups":["MOD_SW"],"Id":64,"Url":"akatherm"},
{"Email":"someone@some.com","Name":"Albrand","Groups":["MOD_PI,"MOD_GE"],"Id":23,"Url":"albrand"}]
```

I want to create a new array (for select tag) with distinct `Groups`.

This `Groups` is an array.

I want that selectbox to have the following values:

```
MOD_SW
MOD_PI
MOD_GE
```

My JS:

```
UpdateSelectMenu: function (selectId, data) {
      $(selectId).empty();
      $(selectId).html("<option value='all' selected='selected'>All groups</option>");
      var array_unique_values = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < data.Groups.length; i++) {
         for (var j = i+1; j < data.Groups.length; j++) {
            if (data.Groups[i] === data.Groups[j]) {
               j = ++i;
            }
         }
         array_unique_values.push(data.Groups[i]);
      }

      array_unique_values = array_unique_values.sort();

      $.each(array_unique_values, function (k, v) {
         $(selectId).append("<option value='" + v + "'>" + v + "</option>");
      });
   }
```

I tried also

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {  //browse whole data
         for (var j = 0; j < data[i].Groups.length; j++) {  //browse Groups array
            for (var k = j + 1; j < data[i].Groups.length; k++) {
               if (data[i].Groups[j] === data[i].Groups[k]) {
                  continue;
               }
            }

            array_unique_values.push(data[i].Groups[j]);
         }
      }
```

But error appears as: `Groups.length` is null or not an object

This code appends to `select` tag the Group values but it appears as duplicates because `Groups` is an array.

I have to create a new `for` statement to browse the `Groups` array ?

Or there is another alternative to avoid nested `for` statements ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 nested loops could do the job:

```
var data = [... your data ...];
var groups = [];
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    $.each(item.Groups, function(j, group) {
        if ($.inArray(group, groups) == -1) {
            groups.push(group);
        }
    });    
});

// at this stage groups = ["MOD_SW", "MOD_PI", "MOD_GE"]
```

and if you wanted to directly append options to your dropdown:

```
var groups = [];
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    $.each(item.Groups, function(j, group) {
        if ($.inArray(group, groups) == -1) {
            groups.push(group);
            $(selectId).append(
                $('<option/>', {
                    value: group,
                    text: group
                })
            );
        }
    });    
});
```

---

UPDATE:

And to make this more efficient you could define a static `dtstinct` method:

```
$.extend({
    distinct : function(arr) {
       var result = [];
       $.each(arr, function(index, value) {
           if ($.inArray(value, result) == -1) {
               result.push(value);
           }
       });
       return result;
    }
});
```

and then use the `.map` method:

```
var data = [... your data ...];
var groups = $.distinct($(data).map(function() {
    return this.Groups;    
}));
$.each(groups, function(index, group) {
    $(selectId).append(
        $('<option/>', {
            value: group,
            text: group
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: $.inArray is making a loop (if indexOf is unavailable) and I think that's quite inefficient.

Comment: all respect for you Darin :) You saved my life. These `$.each` didn't passed through my brain.

Comment: @mgechev, good point. I have updated my answer with an alternative which is more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

First look at the last group: `"Groups":["MOD_PI,MOD_GE"]`
Don't you need to close the quotes after MOD_PI and open them after the comma or this is a set of groups?

If this with the quotes is problem the your script can look something like this:

```
var obj = [{"Email":"someone@some.com","Name":"ACO", "Groups":["MOD_SW","MOD_PI","MOD_GE"],"Id":63,"Url":"aco"},
{"Email":"someone@some.com","Name":"Agpo", "Groups":["MOD_PI"],"Id":22,"Url":"agpo"},
{"Email":"someone@some.com","Name":"Akatherm", "Groups":["MOD_SW"],"Id":64,"Url":"akatherm"},
{"Email":"someone@some.com","Name":"Albrand", "Groups":["MOD_PI","MOD_GE"],"Id":23,"Url":"albrand"}]

var temp = {}, 
    result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i+=1) {
    for (var j = 0; j < obj[i]['Groups'].length; j+=1) {
        if (typeof temp[obj[i]['Groups'][j]] === 'undefined') {
            result.push(obj[i]['Groups'][j]);
            temp[obj[i]['Groups'][j]] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

If this is a set of groups:

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i+=1) {
    for (var j = 0; j < obj[i]['Groups'].length; j+=1) {
        currentGroups = obj[i]['Groups'][j].split(',');
        for (var k = 0; k < currentGroups.length; k += 1) {
            currentGroups[k] = currentGroups[k].replace(/ /g,"");
            if (typeof temp[currentGroups[k]] === 'undefined') {
                result.push(currentGroups[k]);
                temp[currentGroups[k]] = true;
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

I think that's the most efficient way because you're checking for duplicates with O(1) and you don't have to do extra work (for example sort any array).

Comment: You're welcome. I've posted version where you can check even for a set of groups. I think that this is going to help you in both cases. Greetings!