# How can I remove duplication from list

Tags: javascript

I have this kind of list from my web service. I want to eliminate username duplication:

```
Mylist = [{
    "username": "Plr1",
    "is_online": true,
    "email": null,
    "message": null,
    "direction": 1,
    "image_url": ""
}, {
    "username": "plr2",
    "is_online": false,
    "email": "",
    "message": null,
    "direction": 1,
    "image_url": ""
}, {
    "username": "plr1",
    "is_online": false,
    "email": "",
    "message": null,
    "direction": 1,
    "image_url": null
}];
```

Is there a function that allows me to remove duplicated values (one of elements=Plr1)?

Comment: use a loop to create a new array or splice (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) the entries

Comment: This link can be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786197/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-which-contains-array

Comment: [`_.uniq(Mylist, function(x) { return x.username })`](http://underscorejs.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/ZgYbB/

NOTE: The last for loop is just to show that items were removed and what is left in the array.

JS:

```
var Mylist= [{"username":"Plr1","is_online":true,"email":null,"message":null,"direction":1,"image_url":""},{"username":"plr2","is_online":false,"email":"","message":null,"direction":1,"image_url":""},{"username":"plr1","is_online":false,"email":"","message":null,"direction":1,"image_url":null} ];

for (var i = 0; i < Mylist.length; i++) {
    for(var j = i + 1; j < Mylist.length; j++) {
        if(Mylist[i].username.toLowerCase() == Mylist[j].username.toLowerCase())
            Mylist.splice(j, 1);
    }
}

//Not needed just proof that items were removed.
for (var i = 0; i < Mylist.length; i++) {
   alert(Mylist[i].username);
}
```

Comment: This is a copy of my earlier answer that won't perform as well (due to nested looping)... why give it the checkmark?

Comment: I didn't copy your answer, I jsfiddled and made my answer.  Great minds do think alike and I agree that there are faster methods for this.  My answer is a simple example that works, given the size of this array no issues will be noticed due to time of operation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var Mylist = [{"username":"Plr1","is_online":true,"email":null,"message":null,"direction":1,"image_url":""},{"username":"plr2","is_online":false,"email":"","message":null,"direction":1,"image_url":""},{"username":"plr1","is_online":false,"email":"","message":null,"direction":1,"image_url":null} ];
var keys = [];
var newList = Mylist.filter(
    function(x){ 
        var val = x.username.toLowerCase();
        if (!keys[val]) {
            keys[val] = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);
keys = null;
console.log(newList);
```

It will not work in older browsers out of the box. If you look at the link I posted to above, there is a pollyfill to make them work.

Comment: props for showing the newer method I love it, +1 for showing off the new browsers capability...if only we could rid the world of IE < 10

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want (assuming you're looking for case-insensitive comparison of usernames).

EDIT to add Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vBZhR/

```
var Mylist= [{"username":"Plr1","is_online":true,"email":null,"message":null,"direction":1,"image_url":""},{"username":"plr2","is_online":false,"email":"","message":null,"direction":1,"image_url":""},{"username":"plr1","is_online":false,"email":"","message":null,"direction":1,"image_url":null} ];

dedupe(Mylist);
function dedupe(list) {
    var usernames = {};
    for (var i in list) {
        if (usernames[list[i].username.toLowerCase()]) {
            list.splice(i, 1);
        } else {
            usernames[list[i].username.toLowerCase()] = true;
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Where's the love?  This is the first, correct, and best answer.  Why upvotes for later answers that won't perform as well or be supported as widely?

Comment: you have proof to validate your claims? If so show the demo i'll upvote this in 1 second if that's the case.